# You tube videos are not playing in mobile

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have used YouTube Iframe API to view videos in my html page.
My code works correctly on my browser.
I have packaged the HTML and created the Cordova android app.
Now I am not able to play some videos and getting error message.
The following is the error message
"This video contains content from Tseries Music. It is restricted from playback on certain sites"

Please tell me the root cause and solution.

Comment: Did you actually *read* the error message? The video you tried to play is not allowed to be embedded on whatever your application appears to be. You need to ask "Tseries Music" nicely to allow playback.

Comment: But then how it can run on my browser.

Comment: When you say that it is running on your web browser, do you mean you can watch the video on your web browser in Youtube? The error message you are getting restricts this particular video from being embedded any place else other than Youtube. Hence, then only place this video can be watched is the YouTube website and this video cannot be played on any other site or app whether or not you are using the YouTube API. As Matti suggested, you need to ask Tseries to allow playback for your app/website.